# Reverse Zip a Collection

Tags: swift, collections, functional-programming, zip

I'm looking to do a "reverse zip" on a collection. Essentially meaning:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
let (left, right) = a.reverseZip()

print(left)  // [1, 3, 5, 7] 
print(right) // [2, 4, 6]
```

I have an implementation that seems to work (see my answer listed below), but I have two questions that I'm hoping we could discuss:

1. What's the correct name for this kind of operation? It's not exactly the opposite of `zip` (and I'm certain this pattern exists elsewhere in another functional language)
2. Is there a more optimal algorithm for this method?

Comment: careful, `reverse` is a term of art meaning iteration from end to start, not "reverse operation". I would suggest terms like `interleave` and `deinterleave`

Comment: See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/192142/49674

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a seed of an idea.  Instead of returning arrays, it would be more efficient to return sequences.

Here is an `Array` extension that returns two `LazyMapSequence<StrideTo<Int>, Element>`.  The advantage is that is doesn't actually generate the sequences; they are provided on demand because they're `lazy`.  This is much like the way `reversed()` works on an `Array`.

```
extension Array {

    func reverseZip() -> (LazyMapSequence<StrideTo<Int>, Element>, LazyMapSequence<StrideTo<Int>, Element>) {

        let left = stride(from: 0, to: self.count, by: 2).lazy.map { self[$0] }
        let right = stride(from: 1, to: self.count, by: 2).lazy.map { self[$0] }

        return (left, right)
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
let (left, right) = a.reverseZip()

// iterate left
for i in left {
    print(i)
}
```

> ```
> 1
> 3
> 5
> 7
> ```

```
// turn them into arrays to print them
print(Array(left))
```

> ```
> [1, 3, 5, 7]
> ```

```
print(Array(right))
```

> ```
> [2, 4, 6]
> ```

I'm sure this can be generalized to something more general than `Array`.  That is left as an exercise to the reader.

---

**If you want two arrays**

If you really want the two arrays, then you'd just return the result of `map` (taking out `lazy`):

```
extension Array {

    func reverseZip() -> ([Element], [Element]) {

        let left = stride(from: 0, to: self.count, by: 2).map { self[$0] }
        let right = stride(from: 1, to: self.count, by: 2).map { self[$0] }

        return (left, right)
    }
}
```

Comment: Keeps giving me `SWIFT RUNTIME BUG: unable to demangle type of field '_transform'. mangled type name is 'q_7ElementSTQzc'`

Comment: @Carpsen90, it does for me too.  And yet, it still works.

Comment: Yes, using stride was my first instinct too. Why not remove `lazy` and return `([Element], [Element])`?

Comment: @Carpsen90, creating the arrays will be slower if you're just going to iterate perhaps just part of them.  The idea is to delay the creation of the array if it isn't really needed.

Comment: Nice answer. It might be good to show how to do what the OP asked for, however. That would be a simple matter of changing the function to return 2 arrays of type `[Element]` and using `return (Array(left), Array(right))` to turn the sequences into `Array`s.

Comment: You could define this for a RandomAccessCollection (the original question was for a Collection, not an Array).

Comment: @MartinR, I tried that but then I needed to restrict Index to Int to make stride work. Does that provide much extra capability for the user in a real sense?

Answer (score 1):

```
extension Collection {

    func reverseZip() -> ([Element], [Element]) {

        var left  = [Element]()
        var right = [Element]()

        let capacity = Double(self.count) / 2.0
        left .reserveCapacity(Int(ceil(capacity)))
        right.reserveCapacity(self.count / 2)

        for element in self {

            if left.count > right.count {
                right.append(element)
            } else {
                left.append(element)
            }
        }
        return (left, right)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE (03/10/18)**
Thank you all for your help. Seems like a lot of you latched onto `Stride`, which is definitely a good way to go. I resisted this approach for 2 reasons:

1. I'm keen to keep this function as an extension of `Collection`, rather than `Array`
2. Strictly speaking, the `startIndex` of a given `Collection` isn't necessary 0, and the progression of indexes isn't necessarily an increment of 1 each time.

Martin R's approach of using a custom iterator definitely seemed like the right approach, so I used that along with the [WWDC 2018's implementation of "EveryOther"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018-229/?time=249) to create a standard sequential iterator that simply goes along two elements in each while loop block, till it hits the end.

```
extension Collection {

    func deinterleave() -> ([Element], [Element]) {
        let smallHalf = count / 2
        let bigHalf   = count - smallHalf

        var left  = [Element]()
        var right = [Element]()

        left .reserveCapacity(bigHalf)
        right.reserveCapacity(smallHalf)

        let start = self.startIndex
        let end   = self.endIndex

        var iter = start
        while iter != end {
            left.append(self[iter])
            iter = index(after: iter)

            if iter == end { break }
            right.append(self[iter])

            iter = index(after: iter)
        }
        return (left, right)
    }
}

let a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
print(a.deinterleave()) // ([1, 3, 5, 7], [2, 4, 6])
```

Without a doubt, there is some scope to improve this further and use vacawama's `LazyMapSequence` implementation, but for now this does everything I need it to.

Comment: The truncation caused by integer division by 2 will mean that `left`'s capacity is too small by 1 when `count` is an odd number.

Comment: Good call @Alexander

Comment: Updated to fix this issue

Comment: Better: `let smallerHalfCount = count / 2; let biggerHalfCount = count - smallerHalf; left.reserveCapacity(biggerHalfCount); right.reserveCapacity(biggerHalfCount)`

Comment: You can also use `formIndex(after: &iter)` to advance the index.

Answer (score 1):

Based on vacawama's idea to return *lazy collections* instead of arrays,
here is a possible generalization to arbitrary collections with arbitrary strides:

```
extension Collection {

    func makeStrideIterator(stride: Int) -> AnyIterator<Element> {
        precondition(stride > 0, "The stride must be positive")
        var it = makeIterator()
        var first = true
        return AnyIterator<Element> {
            if first {
                first = false
            } else {
                // Skip `stride - 1` elements:
                for _ in 1..<stride {
                    guard let _ = it.next() else { return nil }
                }
            }
            return it.next()
        }
    }
}
```

The method returns an `AnyIterator` (which is both an iterator and a sequence)
of the collection elements at the positions

```
0, stride, 2*stride, ...
```

Unzipping an array (or any other collection) can then be done with

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let left = a.makeStrideIterator(stride: 2)
let right = a.dropFirst().makeStrideIterator(stride: 2)

for e in left { print(e) }
// 1, 3, 5
for e in right { print(e) }
// 2, 4
```

Here is an example for picking every third character from a string:

```
for c in "ABCDEFG".makeStrideIterator(stride: 3) {
    print(c)
}
// A D G
```

The special case of unzipping into two arrays can then be implemented as

```
extension Collection {
    func unzip() -> ([Element], [Element]) {
        return (Array(makeStrideIterator(stride: 2)),
                Array(dropFirst().makeStrideIterator(stride: 2)))
    }
}
```

Example:

```
print([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].unzip())
// ([1, 3, 5], [2, 4])
```

Comment: Is this message `SWIFT RUNTIME BUG: unable to demangle type of field '_position'. mangled type name is '5IndexSlQz'` inevitable?

Comment: This the right answer, you could also add this to Collection: `func unzip(into n: Int) -> [[Element]] { return (0..<n).map{Array(dropFirst($0).makeStrideIterator(stride: n))} }`

Comment: @Carpsen90: I do not get such a warning (or any other warning).

Comment: I'm on Xode Version 10.0 (10A255), Swift 4.2, using a playground

Comment: @Carpsen90: Indeed, same warning here in a Playground, but not in a compiled project. – I have no idea, but there seem to be some related bug reports, e.g. https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8354